# Python IMAP Search from or to designated email address

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I am using this with Gmail's SMTP server, and I would like to search via IMAP for emails   either sent to or received from an address.

This is what I have:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

mail.login('user', 'pass')
mail.list()
mail.select("[Gmail]/All Mail")

status, email_ids = mail.search(None, 'TO "tech163@fusionswift.com" OR FROM "tech163@fusionswift.com"')
```

The last line of the error is: `imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']`

Not sure how I'm supposed to do that kind of OR statement within python's `imaplib`. If someone can quickly explain what's wrong or point me in the right direction, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error you are receiving is generated from the server because it can't parse the *search query* correctly. In order to generate a valid query follow the [RFC 3501](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501), in page 49 it is explained in detail the structure.

For example your search string to be correct should be:

```
'(OR (TO "tech163@fusionswift.com") (FROM "tech163@fusionswift.com"))'
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the correct syntax for searching (there wasn't many useful pages on Google).

Comment: @Tech163 You're welcome. With these kind of protocols you have to go to straight to the source(RFCs) in order to get the best info.

Comment: It appears that `FROM` may need to be changed to `HEADER FROM` etc. Only the latter worked for me.

Comment: @OlehPrypin I can confirm that on the MS Exchange server `HEADER FROM` worked for me.

Comment: The syntax standard might also be helpful to explain: [ABNF - RFC2234](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2234)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use IMAP query builder from https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from imap_tools import A, AND, OR, NOT
# AND
A(text='hello', new=True)  # '(TEXT "hello" NEW)'
# OR
OR(text='hello', date=datetime.date(2000, 3, 15))  # '(OR TEXT "hello" ON 15-Mar-2000)'
# NOT
NOT(text='hello', new=True)  # 'NOT (TEXT "hello" NEW)'
# complex
A(OR(from_='from@ya.ru', text='"the text"'), NOT(OR(A(answered=False), A(new=True))), to='to@ya.ru')
```

Of course you can use all library tools